# How to match a word not following a defined pattern?

Tags: regular-expression

I have the following text file:

```
1: This is a book.
2: Here is the book for you.
3: There are book.
4: You can read the book.
5: Is book good to read?
```

I want to find all occurrences of `book` not following `a` or `the`, that is, the `book` in Line 3,5 but not those on lines 1,2,4.

I tried to use the following search pattern:

```
[^a|the] book
```

however, this is only to check one character, but not the whole word.

Answer (score 3):

The brackets are for chars. Use subpattern (parentheses) instead.

```
\%(a\|the\)\@3<! book
```

`\%( ... \)` --- a (unnumbered) submatch

`a\|the` --- "a" or "the"

`\@3<!` --- NO match behind (3 bytes lookback)

Comment: The 3 shouldnt be necessary, right?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Unnecessary, but strongly recommended due to performance issues. See `:h /\@<!`.

Comment: well, I need to match a word but not led a defined pattern. I think there is a negative lookahead command(?)

Comment: @Matt It seems @3<1 is not working, After remove 3, **\(a\|the\)\@<! book** is a workaround.

Comment: @ShihSyuanHuang What is "@3<1"? I wrote `\@3<!`

Comment: It is a typo, I mean @3<! is not working

Comment: @ShihSyuanHuang It does work with the latest Vim version running the default config. If it does not work for you, you're free to omit it - as it was already mentioned, "3" is optional here.

Comment: Thanks for a lot~